# Wrong rendering of diacritical characters in JSON file

Tags: json, azure, configuration, character-encoding

This thing's been bugging me for the last hour, i have [this exposed json file](http://vlashentsite.azurewebsites.net/langs/bio-en.json) 
that should look like this : `{
  "bio": {
    "meettheguy": "Meet this guy",
    "occupation": "Musician",
    "bio": "Test with diacritical marks : ááçë;"
  }
}`

but instead looks like this : `{
  "bio": {
    "meettheguy": "Meet this guy",
    "occupation": "Musician",
    "bio": "Test with diacritical marks : ����;"
  }
}`

This is a MVC app hosted on an Azure server and apparently there is something wrong with the encoding during the JSON retrieve.
At this moment I cannot figure it out so any help or pointing at some probable right direction would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"During the JSON retrieve": Rather, it seems the problem is with the storage or generation, not the retrieval.

Your server says Content-Type: "application/json; charset=utf-8" which is quite normal for JSON. However, the bytes are not UTF-8 encoded text. Perhaps, it is stored or generated incorrectly, causing the wrong thing to be sent.

JSON should be encoded as UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32. [RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-9).

Based on the bytes and the text expected to contain "ááçë", the following encodings are what the source might be incorrectly saved as:

- CP1250
- CP1252
- CP1254
- CP1258
- CP28591
- CP28592
- CP28593
- CP28599
- CP28605

So, go upstream and fix whatever caused JSON to be saved or generated in one of those encodings, chose an encoding appropriate to JSON and make sure your server says which it is.